# Connecting to IRC using Python

Tags: python, irc, twitch

I am new to programming and am trying to create a simple Send Only IRC client for Twitch using Python.

But I am having problems from the start of my code :( , apparently after using the commands to connect and sending my password and username I don't seem to receive a response from the server.

Don't know what i am doing wrong, any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

The Code:

```
username = '~omitted~'
password = 'oauth:~omitted~'
channel = '#channelname'

irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect(('irc.twitch.tv', 6667))
irc.recv(4096)
irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
irc.send('NICK ' + username + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + username + '\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')


while True:
    data = irc.recv(4096)
    print(data)
    if data.find('PONG') != -1:
        irc.send('PONG ' + data.split()[1] + '\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code I was using for irc logging:

```
readbuffer = ''
s=socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('NICK %s\r\n' % NICK)
s.send('USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n' % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))

log = False
while 1:
  readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
  temp       = string.split(readbuffer, '\n')
  readbuffer = temp.pop()
  for line in temp:
    line = string.split(string.rstrip(line))
    if(line[0] == 'PING'):
      s.send('PONG %s\r\n' % line[1])
    else:
      if(line[-1]=='+x'):
        print ' '.join(line)
        s.send('JOIN #twitlive\r\n')
        log = True
      else:
        if not log:
          print ' '.join(line[3:])
        else:
          if len(line) > 3:
            fullname = ''
            name = ''
            if line[0].split('!')[0][0] == ':':
              fullname = line[0][1:]
              name = line[0].split('!')[0][1:]
            if line[3:][0][0] == ':':
              ...
              ...
```

Maybe you find something useful in it